# SpamAssasin TLD blocking

Tags: spam-prevention, email-filter, spamassassin, tld

I have configured spamassasin in my hosting to block some spammer TLDs.
The blacklist email is just as this:

*@*.asia
*@*.bar
*@*.best
*@*.bid
*@*.buzz
*@*.cam
*@*.casa
*@*.cloud
*@*.club
*@*.cyou
*@*.diet
*@*.digital
*@*.fun
*@*.guru
*@*.host
*@*.icu
*@*.live
*@*.monster
*@*.pro
*@*.pw
*@*.rest
*@*.site
*@*.space
*@*.surf
*@*.today
*@*.top
*@*.uno
*@*.work
*@*.world
*@*.xyz

This has been working correctly until now, but now I need to add *@*.co because I'm receiving a lot of spam from the .co TLD.
The problem is that if I add *@*.co spamassasin removes also the .com TLD, and I need to receive emails from it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Whitelist the address you want before .co is blacklisted.  .co is not .com so make sure your entry does not have an autocomplete or *.* in the entry.

Comment: . should be star.star

Comment: Hi John !
Thank you for point this.
I have noticed that the text in my question is incomplete the entries are really like *@*.asia, ... *@*.xyz, so they have a wildcard for the email address

Comment: sorry, the entries are really like star@star.asia, ... star@star.xyz, so they have a wildcard for the email address.
I can whitelist star@star.com in the whitelist spamassassin configuration page inside the DirectAdmin Control Panel, but is seems to apply after the blacklist...